# How to connect Sparrow wallet to Bitcoin Core on a different machine but the same network

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, sparrow-wallet

I have a Raspiblitz set up on a Pi 4 and am trying to connect Sparrow wallet to Bitcoin Core from another machine on the same network. I have read through the instructions at sparrow.com/docs but cannot get Sparrow to connect.

Looking at my bitcoin.conf file on the Raspiblitz the layout is slightly different to the layout in the example:

Example Layout:

```
rpcuser=bitcoin
rpcpassword=yourpassword
[main]
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcbind=192.168.0.10
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=192.168.0.0/16
```

My layout

```
rpcuser=bitcoin
rpcpassword=yourpassword
main.rpcport=8332
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
main.rpcbind=127.0.0.1:8332
```

I have inserted my specific IP address (192.168.1.10) by adding the lines:

```
rpcallowip=192.168.1.0/16
rpcbind=192.168.1.10
```

In that order underneath like in the example. I don't know much about the CIDR notation at the end of the rpcallowip address but have also tried 192.168.1.0/24 and the address itself without the / (192.168.1.10). I've also tried main. in front of the rcpbind for my IP.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong. I have looked for answers but there are not many too many guides for this aspect of Sparrow.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible you have a firewall blocking the port? try adding a rule to allow connections on the rpc port (8332 as you specified)